# Can I Convert ElasticSearch data node to non-data node without data loss?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a cluster of 4 elasticsearch nodes and they all have node.data=true. I'd like to convert one of them to being a non-data node; is that as simple as just changing the yaml file and restarting, or will I risk data loss if I do that?

Or am I better off just standing up another VM and adding it to the cluster as a non-data node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple ways you can achieve this with out any data loss!

**Approach-1:**

> Move all shards from data node `X` to other data nodes using **Shard Allocation Filtering** settings then stop node `X` then start it as non-data node.

You can either whitelist(`index.routing.allocation.include.{attribute}`) or blacklist(`index.routing.allocation.exclude.{attribute}`) data nodes from storing shards by using **Shard Allocation Filtering** settings. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html#shard-allocation-filtering).

```
Warning: If you have very large indices spread across the cluster then this approach may take long time to move shards and it depends on your bandwidth.
```

**Approach-2:**

> Making sure all indices having replica shards of at least 1 and
>   stop data node `X` then start it as non-data node

This may look simple but little *risky*. Your cluster state may go from `red` to `yellow` and `green`. You can read more about this case [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_coping_with_failure.html#_coping_with_failure).

**Its always recommended taking backup of whole data before doing these kind of changes to cluster**

Here `X` is the data node which you want to convert to non-data node.

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm (I took approach 2 even though it seemed riskier because there was less chance of me messing something up with the filtering.